# Using OAUTH2 to secure individual kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, oauth-2.0

I need to be able to implement security (more specifically authorization) on a per topic basis for a large Kafka implementation.  Ideally, I would like to use OAUTH2 (client_credentials flow), however from reading the documentation (Confluent and Apache, and third party vendors) it appears that the authorization for topics can only be done globally.  In other words, Kafka OAUTH2 security uses a single scope in its configuration which is required to access any/all topics. Rather I require different scopes applied for authorization for each individual topic.

Is there a documented way of doing this (perhaps I missed it in the Kafka documentation) or is there a third party that does this out of the box?

An an alternative, I am able to configure a microservice facade in front of topics (ie. OAUTH2 scope verification occurs in the microservice prior to consuming or publishing a message).  Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: Apache Ranger can be used to control ACL to individual topics. Not sure about OAUTH.... OpenPolicyAgent as well has a Kafka plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all sounds possible but you'll need to implement a few things:

- Custom Authorizer

  The authorization logic is pluggable via the [`authorizer.class.name`](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#authorizer.class.name) setting and it allows you to provide an implementation of the [`Authorizer`](http://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/server/authorizer/Authorizer.html) interface.

  This class will be invoked when Kafka handles requests, see http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#operations_resources_and_protocols for the breakdown.

  Within this class you can use whatever logic you want to perform the authorization. You are provided with the `Principal` describing the user and the list of permissions to check.
- Custom OAuth callback/Principal Builder

  Not entirely sure what's possible with the built-in OAuth authenticator. If it does not handle multiple scopes, you'll need to implement your own [`AuthenticateCallbackHandler`](http://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/security/auth/AuthenticateCallbackHandler.html). If you want to have the scopes usable in the `Authorizer`, you'll probably also need a custom [`KafkaPrincipalBuilder`](http://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/security/auth/KafkaPrincipalBuilder.html), so scopes are stored in the `Principal`.

These are high level guidelines, as it's hard to be more detailed considering this requires a number of custom parts. Hopefully that's enough to give you an idea of what to do.