# Mixing SSL only and plaintext topics in Kafka

Tags: ssl, text, apache-kafka

I am interested in having a mix of encrypted and plaintext topics on the same Kafka cluster. Some topics would be accesible through plaintext protocol while others would (must) not.

I have been going through [Kafka encryption with SSL documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_ssl) and several other entries through the web, and I have the impression that a per topic security configuration might not be supported out of the box with simple configuration, but would like to validate this impression with more experienced people.

All related documentation I find shows how to enable secured and plaintext protocols for the whole cluster, but I could not find any way to do so per topic. Is that currently possible? Perhaps by implementing a custom Authorizer class, although ideally I was looking for something more "out of the box", like a simple topic configuration which would specifically indicate which protocols this topic would support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found this similar question that reinforces my impression that I would need a custom Authorizer class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315936/using-oauth2-to-secure-individual-kafka-topics

Comment: You can advertise plaintext and ssl protocols on separate ports for the cluster, but not per topic ... I assume if you were to produce to the ssl port, then consume from the plaintext port, it would be encrypted, so the deserializer would fail. If that's not good enough, then an authorizer seems to be best

Comment: I understand what you mean. If the topics contents are encrypted, by definition plain text access would not return anything of value (actually, it would not even work). So although the plaintext protocol is available, it would be useless. Yes, I think that works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@JPS
i think you might mix things up here. What exactly do you want to achive?
The link from your initial post refers to a documentation, how to set up ssl-in-flight-encryption and/or authentication with your kafka-cluster. But this does not alter the data, that is written into your topics. Kafka does not provide an out-of-the-box "data-at-rest-encryption"-solution. So, what is it exactly?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your reply. Essentially, be able to have a per-topic option to specify if a topic must use encryption or not. In production an environment is a lot more controlled, but in dev or sandbox cluster, if I want a mixed cluster in which some topics are to be encrypted while others should not, either I need to keep a separate list of record for developers to know, or else I risk someone producing the wrong type of message (encrypted in plaintext topic or other way round) causing deserialization errors.

Comment: Ok, so to be clear on that: you want to store the data, that is written to a topic, encrypted, at least for some of your topics, and for others not. As said above, you need to implement a "data-at-rest encryption" solution. The "data-at-rest-encryption" though has nothing to do with schema-validation. If you want to enforce schemas in your topics messages, you need something like the confluent schema registry.